# The relationship between the Weyl group and Isometries of a Maximal Flat

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, weyl-group

Let $M$ be a symmetric space of the noncompact or compact type with $G := \text{Isom}(M)^0$.
It's *Weyl group* is defined as
$$
W := N_G(A) / Z_G(A),
$$
where $A \leq G$ is a maximal abelian subgroup. One can show that $W \cong N_K(A)/Z_K(A)$ where $K = G_p$ is the stabilizer of a point $p \in M$.

The intuition on the Weyl group is that if $F \subseteq M$ is a maximal flat, then the isometries in $\text{Isom}(F) \cong \mathbb{R}^r \rtimes O(r)$ which are coming from isometries of $G$ are exactly those whose orthogonal part is in $W$. This means that the image of the map
$$
G_F :=\{ g \in G : gF =F\} \to \text{Isom}(F).
$$
should be isomorphic to $A \rtimes W$.

**Questions:**

1. How can I construct such an isomorphism explicitly?
2. Is $G_F$ itself a semidirect product of something with $W$?

I have tried several variations, for example constructing a split short exact sequence with the image of the above map in the middle, but It doesn't work out. I also couldnt find a treatment of this relationship in the books by Helgason or Ebelrein where this isomorphism is constructed.

Comment: I do not understand the first question (I think, your description is quite explicit, although requires some nontrivial theorems from Lie theory). As for the 2nd question, the answer is negative: Weyl group does not always lift into $G$. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13139/can-we-realize-weyl-group-as-a-subgroup

Comment: Do you know about a description of $W$ where one sees the isomorphism $\text{im}\Bigl(G_F \to \text{Isom}(F)\Bigr) \cong \mathbb{R}^r \rtimes W$?

Comment: Yes: Pick a point $o\in F$ and let $F_i\subset F$'s be maximal singular flats  through $o$. Then $W< Isom(F)$ is the group generated by reflections in these flats. One can also see simple reflections by choosing a component $\Delta$ of $F-\cup_i F_i$. Its closure is a Weyl chamber. Simple reflections are the reflections in the singular flats containing facets of $cl(\Delta)$.